# Editing "Row-Action" Menu in APEX Interactive Grid

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

How can I change the available options inside the **Selection** part of a **Row Actions** Menu in Apex?

I was able to change the options on the **Line Menu**, but I'm still struggling to change anything on the **Selection Menu**.

Selection Menu on the left & Line Menu on the right

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for the editing I wanted. Sharing it here for someone that might want to use it too.

```
function(config) {
    config.initActions = function( actions ) {
        // löscht die Option "Single Row-Ansicht"
        actions.remove("single-row-view");
        actions.remove("selection-duplicate");
        actions.remove("selection-refresh");
    };
    return config;
}
```

By using the **remove** action, rather than the **widget.disable** I was able to remove the fields from the **Selection Menu** that I meant to change.

[image]

Edit: There's a few new options that APEX 18.2 seems to have added. Here are the codes I found so far that disables them. The ones I still haven't figured out how to remove are the "Fill" and "Clear" options. Hope it's useful to anyone trying to get rid of these options.

The code that targets the first two options shown here are:

```
actions.remove("selection-copy");
actions.remove("selection-duplicate");
```

I've attempted using the "selection" prefix for the fill and clear options, yet to no avail. If anyone knows their codes, please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this:

- Add that Code on Execute When Page Load at Page Level property

```js
   

 $(function() {
    // Add new Element in the selection action menu
    $("#emp_ig_selection_actions_menu").menu("option").items.push({
            type: "action",
            id: "irHello",
            hide: false,
            label: 'hello world',
            icon: 'fa fa-home',
            action: function() {
                alert("hello world");
            }
        });
    
 // Disable Items in the Menu  
 apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").disable("selection-duplicate");
        
 apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").disable("selection-revert");
    });
```

To understand how the Menu Widget works, have a look here
https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.2/AEXJS/menu.html

[image]

[image]

Demo: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=28835:2

Comment: The new custom options I was able to implement here, though the second part of the code, with the "disable", I wasn't.

I also checked with the element search on the demo application you've posted, and I've managed to find my "true" region id, basically looking like this: 

`// Disable Items in the Menu  
 apex.region("ig_gid").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").disable("selection-duplicate");`

Comment: OK. you can have a look here to show how the Menu Widget works https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.2/AEXJS/menu.html

Comment: Sorry if I sound ignorant, but I can't find a solution for it by reading the widgets documentation. I assumed that by adapting the code, the function I want removed would be removed.

Should I create my own interactive grid with these options to then be able to deactivate it? Would that be the best idea?

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove? please give more Details?

Comment: I'd like to be able to remove the options like in your code, "selection-duplicate" and such. I was able to add more buttons with the code, but the removal just won't work. I also tried using the "disabled" option with indexes of the menus, but it didn't work either.  I'm lost on why the code doesn't work, considering I have the correct IG ids. Reading the widgets documentation had nothing on it, which is why asked.

Comment: Can you show me your Code how you made that? you should run it into $(function() {  });

Comment: This was the part that didn't work:

`apex.region("ig_gid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews").disable("selection-duplicate");
 apex.region("ig_gid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews").disable("selection-delete");`

Comment: Try that on execute when page load

$(function() { 
apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").disable("selection-duplicate");
        
 apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").disable("selection-delete");
});

//emp is the static id for the GRID

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie too. So decoratively I was able to completely remove the "Row Action " Line options by selecting :- Page Designer -> Content Body-> APEX$Row_Action->GO TO Right Side -> security -> Authorization Scheme -> { Not 'role that has access to the page'Rights}

For the tool bar I used a already discovered hack  that I entered in the Java initialization code area under Attributes :

```
function(config) {
  var $ = apex.jQuery;
  var toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(); 
  toolbarData.splice(5,3);
  //remove actions button
  config.autoAddRow = false;
  config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
  return config
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting possibility for a future requirement. I've actually looked into the changes I've had before, considering my APEX version was updated to 18.2, and there's a bunch of new options there. I'm looking into identifying their labels. The previous deleted functions that I used in the solution still work, but now I would like to know the new one's labels.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to omit the "Fill" and "Clear" menu options (plus any others you desire) by combining the solutions of **alli pierre yotti** and **AWildmann**,
i.e. I did exactly as **alli pierre yotti** suggests but replaced the disable() method with remove() as referenced by **AWildmann**.

So here's the code I placed in the "Execute when Page Loads" attribute at the page level.  I also replaced the hardwired quoted region name with a variable just to simplify future changes to the region static id, as well as to make it simpler to copy this code to other pages, but this has no effect on the solution.

```js
$(function() {

  regionStaticId = "emp"

  apex.region(regionStaticId).widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").remove("selection-duplicate");

  apex.region(regionStaticId).widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").remove("selection-copy");

  apex.region(regionStaticId).widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").remove("selection-fill");

  apex.region(regionStaticId).widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").remove("selection-copy-down");

   apex.region(regionStaticId).widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").remove("selection-clear");

});
```

Thanks to the original contributors for the solution, I've only contributed in a superficial way.

I haven't posted on stackoverflow before so apologies if I'm supposed to mark-up the references to the other contributors in a special way.

Answer (score 0):

To hide row-level options (in this case, "Delete record"), I use the following CSS:

[id$='ig_row_actions_menu_5'].a-Menu-item,li[id$='ig_row_actions_menu_5'] + .a-Menu-itemSep{
  display:none
}